# I can not generate signed apk on Android Studio

Tags: android, sign, android-keystore

I've been learning programming on Android Studio and already have an app about to publish. Some points are missing for trying to learn by myself and my question may sound silly. 
3-4 months ago I generated my first signed apk. Since then as I developed my app, sometimes I generated apks to test my app. When I was generating signed apks keystore file (jks) path 
was remembered and I quickly click forward button to generate signed apk. The location of my jks file was "C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\feature\build\outputs". After Android Studio update  I can not generate signed apk with this key. Whatever I do, they all end with "No key with alias '....' found in keystore C:\Users\Me\Desktop\" 
Keystore path is always seems as desktop. I can not change it. When generating apk I already select my existing keystore path but Android Studio always looks for keystore file on desktop.
Another problem is alias name mentioned in the error message is different my existing alias name. Android Studio looks wrong place and wrong alias name. So why is Android Studio acting like this? How can I generate a signed apk again?

Comment: This guide will help if you follow carefully - https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I read it carefully but could not fix problem. Does anybody have other solution?

Comment: Fixed! All I need was cleaning project and rebuild. I think the first two things that needs to be done in such strange behaviors of Android Studio are clean and rebuild!

Comment: Hi @NaciBaşak, glad you found a solution to your problem. Would you mind answering yourself in this question commenting on the solution to your problem? You can mark your answer as correct once you do that.